# How can I delete a pre-existing image from storage before re-downloading using DownloadManager?

Tags: java, android, image, email

I am writing code for an Android app using Eclipse that is supposed to download an image from a URL (which is generated by the app, elsewhere in the code, using GPS information), then attach the newly downloaded image to an e-mail to be sent. I am able to, in general, accomplish this without much issue.
My problem is this: I only want one image downloaded by the app to be present in the device's external storage at any given time. Deleting the image after the email intent does not work, because because the app doesn't always call onStop or onDestroy when switching to another app to send the email. Time-sensitive deleting of the image will not work either, because I cannot assume that the user will send only one email from the app per hour. I want to give the user the freedom of sending as many of these emails (with one newly downloaded image, each) as they wish.
My current method (which works MOST of the time) is this: in the downloadFile method, simply check for the file's existence (I call it sensorMap.png), then delete it if it exists, before downloading a new one. This SHOULD ensure that there may be only one sensorMap.png image in external storage at any given time (EDIT: it does do this), and that when it comes time to attach the image to the email intent, there will be exactly one image ready to go. Instead, <s>I see that sometimes a second sensorMap image is sometimes being downloaded into storage (i.e. "sensorMap-1.png")</s>, OR the image cannot be attached to the email due to a "File size: 0 bytes" error, OR the image cannot be attached due to a "File does not exist" error. I am unsure what the difference between the latter two problems is. **EDIT:** Upon manually examining the contents of the directory I created, it seems that, as intended, I end up with only one image titled "sensorMap.png" at a time; it remains in the directory after the app closes, as expected. However, I still occasionally get the "File size: 0 bytes" message or the "File does not exist." message with no attached image, even though I see that the image DOES exist upon looking in directory afterwards. Other times, everything works just fine. It's rather bewildering.
In addition, there is an issue of the button which sends the email becoming unresponsive occasionally. Most of the time, it prompts the user to select an email client, as intended, but occasionally the button will LOOK as if clicked, but do nothing. When this happens, the logcat does not sense that the button was even clicked (I inserted a println statement to test it).
I am unsure of why my delete-before-download is not working flawlessly; the basic idea, at least, appears to be logically sound. Here is the code pertaining to my issue:
**Code used to download file (in MainCountActivity.java):**

```
//Function to download image given URL. Will use to attach image file to email.
        public void downloadFile(String uRl) {

            //delete existing file first so that only one sensorMap image exists in memory 
            //at any given time.

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SensorLocationImages");
            File checkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SensorLocationImages/sensorMap.png");
            if(checkFile.exists()) 
            {
                //debugging:
                System.out.println("About to delete file!");

                //deleteFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SensorLocationImages");
                checkFile.delete();
            }

            DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    downloadUri);

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Sensor Location Map")
                    .setDescription("Pinpointed is the location from which the log file was sent.")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/SensorLocationImages", "sensorMap.png");

            mgr.enqueue(request);

        }

        public Activity getActivity() //I wasn't sure if this would work, but it did. Or at least appears to.
        { return this; }
```

**Method to send email (in MainCountActivity.java):**

```
public void sendEmail(String toAddress, String ccAddress, String bccAddress, String subject, String body, String attachmentMimeType) throws Exception{
            try {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                emailIntent.setType(attachmentMimeType); //new
                String sToAddress[] = { toAddress };  
                String sCCAddress[] = { ccAddress};  
                String sBCCAddress[] = { bccAddress };  
                emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, sToAddress);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, sCCAddress);  
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, sBCCAddress); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

                //get URI of logfile
                File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + MainCountActivity.dirPath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);

                //create URI arraylist and add first URI
                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                uris.add(uri);

                //get URI of map image and add to arraylist
                //make sure it is there to attach
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SensorLocationImages");
                do {
                    downloadFile(getMapLink());
                    //createDirectoryAndSaveFile(getBitmapFromURL(getMapLink()), "sensorMap.png");
                } while (!file.exists());

                uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/SensorLocationImages/sensorMap.png")));
                        //+ "/sdcard/SensorLocationImages/sensorMap.png")));

                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

                startActivity(emailIntent);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**OnClick method, for my occasional button issue (In MaincountActivity.java):**

```
public void onClick(View v){

                switch(v.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.textView1:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.Reset:
                    {
                        //allowCounting will let the program know when to let it to count or not, depending if Start or Stop button are pressed.
                        logCount=0;
                        mCounter.setText("Total: 0");
                        mToggle.setChecked(false);

                        break;
                    }
                   /* case R.id.toggleButton:
                    {
                        break;
                    }*/
                    case R.id.SendEmail:
                    {
                        //for debugging purposes:
                        System.out.println("Email button being clicked!");

                        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                            {
                              Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is enabled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              try {
                                    sendEmail("","","","Sensor Log Info",getEmailBody(),"multipart/mixed");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                              showGPSAlertForEmail();
                            }

                        break;
                    }

                }
```

Basically, I really want to know why my delete-then-download method has not worked every time. Logcat errors have provided no insight. Thank you for your time.